# Empty error while executing SSIS package in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, ssis, azure-data-factory, ssis-connection-manager

I have created a simple SSIS project and in this project, I have a package that will delete a particular file in Downloads folder.

I deployed this project to Azure. And when I am trying to execute this package using Azure Data Factory then the pipeline fails with an empty error (I am attaching the screenshot here).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cmK6j.png)

### What I have done to fix this error is:

1. I have added self-hosted IR to Azure-SSIS IR as the proxy to access the data on-premise.
2. Set the **ConnectByProxy** as **True**.
3. Converted the project to **Project Deployment Model**.

Please help me out to fix this error and if you need more details then just leave a comment.

Answer (score 0):

**Windows Authentication :**

To access data stores such as SQL servers/file shares on-premises or Azure Files, check the Windows authentication check box.

If this check box is selected, fill in the Domain, Username, and Password fields with the values for your package execution credentials. The domain is Azure, the username is storage account name>, and the password is storage account key> to access Azure Files, for example.

**Using the secrets stored in your Azure Key Vault**

As a substitute, you can leverage secrets from your Azure Key Vault as values. Select the AZURE KEY VAULT check box next to them to do so. Create a new key vault connected service or choose or update an existing one. Then choose your value's secret name and version. You can pick or update an existing key vault or create a new one when creating or editing your key vault connected service. If you haven't previously done so, allow Data Factory managed identity access to your key vault. You may also directly input your secret in the format key vault linked service name>/secret name>/secret version>.

> **Note :** *If you are using Windows Authentication, there are four methods to
> access data stores with Windows authentication from SSIS packages
> running on your Azure-SSIS IR: Access data stores and file shares with
> Windows authentication from SSIS packages in Azure | [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/ssis-azure-connect-with-windows-auth?view=sql-server-ver15)*

Make Sure it Falls under one of such methods, else it could potentially fail at the Run Time.
[image]